# Error Label 'http' already defined Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I don't know how can i get this error. is says :

```
FatalErrorException in web.php line 21
Label 'http' already defined
```

there is no error before. I get this error after my PC hard boot because electrical issue.

Anyone knows how to fix this ?

**UPDATE**

This is line 21 of web.php

[image: it is the route page]

This is the route page of Laravel 5.3.28

Comment: please show line 21 of your `web.php` file

Comment: @AndriyLozynskiy. i have add some update. please take a look

Comment: Can you show us the save method of memberController ?